# a problem about the equivament of two vector groups $(I)$ and $(II)$

Tags: linear-algebra

***Today,I have a problem about the equivament of two vector groups $(I)$ and $(II)$***

$(I),\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$, and they are linear independence

$(II),\alpha_1,\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\alpha_2+\alpha_3,\alpha_3+\alpha_4,\alpha_4-\alpha_1$

***Question:*** Show the vector groups $(I)$ and $(II)$ are equivament

***My trial:***

***The conclusions that I know:***

$1,$Iff $A_{m \times n}C_{n\times s}=B_{m \times s} $ and $r(A)=n$ then $r(B)=r(C)$

$2,max(r(A),r(B)) \le r(A,B) \le r(A)+r(B)$

$3,$ Iff $r(A)=r(B)=r(A,B)$ then the vector groups $A$ and $B$ are equivament

Assuming $B=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4,\beta_5)$ and $A=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$,$C=$

[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
]

Obviously, $r(C)=4$
So I have the equation $B=AC$ And $A$ is line independence $\Rightarrow r(A)=4$

I can get $r(B)=r(C)=4$ $\Rightarrow$ $r(A)=r(B)=4$

To show the problem ,I also to show $r(A)=r(A,B)$

$r(A,B)\ge r(B)=4$

To show $r(A)=r(A,B)$,I must show $r(A,B) \le 4$

However,I don't konw how to do?Can someone help me?Thank sincerely!

Comment: you should definitely consider explaining your notation. For instance, what is $r(X)$ ?

Comment: @Atahualpa Inc,the $r(A)$ means the rank of matrix $A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I suppose you mean that they generate the same space.*

Write
\begin{equation}
\beta_{1} = \alpha_1,
\beta_{2} = \alpha_1+\alpha_2,
\beta_{3} = \alpha_2+\alpha_3,
\beta_{4} = \alpha_3+\alpha_4,
\beta_{5} = \alpha_4-\alpha_1.
\end{equation}
Call $V$ the vector space generated by the $\alpha_{i}$ and $W$ the one generated by the $\beta_{i}$. Clearly $W \subseteq V$.

Now note that $\alpha_{1} = \beta_{1} \in W$, thus $\alpha_{2} = \beta_{2} - \beta_{1} \in W$, thus $\alpha_{3} = \beta_{3} - \alpha_{2} \in W$, and finally $\alpha_{4} = \beta_{4} - \alpha_{3} \in W$. So you have obtained $V \subseteq W$, and thus $V = W$, without using the fact that $\beta_{5} \in W$.

Or is it something else you have in mind?

Comment: ,Dear friend,BTW, I wonder if it is possible for  my method to show that conclusion?

Comment: @tangshutao, let me take a look at it later.